# React JS on first render fails to fetch data and does not returns response ok (200-299)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Recently I am facing issue on my portfolio URL such that on the first reload (maybe after webservices are idle) all my fetch data calls are unsucessful.

It starts working when I hit refresh after the error has occured. I assume backend is not responding quite fast but this is causing issue on the website since there is no data all the sections are getting rendered in an unporper way.

I tried changing webservices but it doesn't seems to help. I am trying to look for a solution such that unless and until the data is not fetch or webservices doesn't starts to respond back I should show some informative message to the audience.

One of the API calls

```js
 const [about, setAbouts] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    async function getRecords() {
      const response = await fetch(`https://portfoliobackend-5h51.onrender.com/aboutdata/`);

      if (!response.ok) {
        const message = `An error occurred: ${response.statusText}`;
        window.alert(message);
        return;
      }

      const records = await response.json();
      setAbouts(records);
    }

    getRecords();
    return;
  }, [about.length]);
```

Answer (score 0):

**One** possible way is that you put `try/catch` block when you are fetching your data (on `getRecords` function) that'd be nice even for when any kind of errors occurs. But since you said your current issue is the server taking up some time "to wake up": **second** thing I'd suggest you is conditional rendering; that is you have default state of rendering a `Loading` component/text and if & when data is fetched successfully you change the state to `true` and render the proper page.

**Edit 2:**
Updated the code to include `retry` state - which will be used to "*wake up*" the server - when it has an initial value of `0`. Since you said in [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75622170/react-js-on-first-render-fails-to-fetch-data-and-does-not-returns-response-ok-2/75622389#comment133426680_75622389): "*on the first render, it goes into the `if` block*" -> in that `if (!response.ok)` block you will both `alert` the user of waking up the server && update the `retry` state by `+1` and have it as a dependency on your `useEffect` hook so that it triggers another call. Now that `retry` has a value of `1` the condition `if (retry >= 1)` is `true` and this time there's a `setTimeout` set to call the `getRecords` function after *35 seconds* since you said "*takes around 30s*", but you can modify the time:

```
const [about, setAbouts] = useState([]);
const [isFetched, setIsFetched] = useState(false);
const [retry, setRetry] = useState(0);

useEffect(() => {
  async function getRecords() {
    try {
      const response = await fetch(`https://portfoliobackend-5h51.onrender.com/aboutdata/`);

      if (!response.ok) {
        //const message = `An error occurred: ${response.statusText}`;
        //window.alert(message);

        // Here I have modified your alert message to better suit the case scenario:
        alert("Kindly await 30 seconds until my server wakes up :)")
        setRetry(prevRetry => prevRetry+1);
        return;
      }

      const records = await response.json();
      setAbouts(records);
      setIsFetched(true);
    } catch (err) {
      alert("Server error, please try again later");
    }
  }

  let timeout;
  if (retry >= 1) {
    timeout = setTimeout(() => {
      getRecords();
    }, 35000); //Modify the time it takes to call "getRecords"
  } else {
    getRecords();
  }

  return () => clearTimeout(timeout);
}, [about.length, retry]);

return (
  <div>
    {!isFetched ? (
      <h1>Loading...</h1>
    ) : (
      about.map((item) => <p>{item}</p>)
    )}
  </div>
);
```

Comment: Thanks!. I understood this but on the first render, it goes into the if block, and alert are the message. During this time I can show Loading Screen for that section but after that manual refresh is needed which is not good at all. 

The web service that I am using goes Idle after 15 minutes of inactivity and takes around 30s to get active again.

I am not sure what is the best option another web service which has good uptime (free like AWS lambda) or something in code.

Comment: Turns out I found one of my older project, also with a server deployed on *Render* - just like yours, but in my case the page waits for 30 seconds until state changes, because my error logic was handled prior to that fetch. So without modifying your code by a lot I'm thinking if you set `setTimeout` after the first *failed* `fetch` call, you `fetch` again lets say after **35s** I will edit my post.

Comment: I'm thinking about the downsides of this, *since I don't see your full code logic*, is: if you are updating `about` state elsewhere while the `retry=1` there would be delay of 35 seconds before `getRecords` is called again (*since you have `about.length` as a dependency to your `useEffect` hook*) so you may need some optimization. But I got minimum information about your app, so instead I give you a code to get past the "*server wake-up issue*" which your post is about.